# Storing keccak hash in bytes32

Tags: solidity

I am using keccak hashing algorithm for converting documents to hashes, the algorithm is producing hashes like:     `**8185f41244d1a00110cff37b60732228623a82e7da905cac00777029887816ff**`

> I want to store this hash in a smart contract in *bytes32* rather than
>   string (bytes32 consumes less gas then string) but I am getting error message as:  `Given parameter is not bytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Given parameter is not bytes**

> You have to add `0x` at starting of your hash
>   `8185f41244d1a00110cff37b60732228623a82e7da905cac00777029887816ff`
>   like this
>   `"0x8185f41244d1a00110cff37b60732228623a82e7da905cac00777029887816ff"`.

Comment: But then, they'll no longer be able to store as bytes32 right? because keccak256 already gives a 32 byte hash.